# while loading report page manually browser crashed and failed to load data, but vugen script is running fine and getting 200 OK response

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

While loading report contains ~ 50K records data manually web browser crashed and failed to respond but vugen script is passed with the same 50K record returning 200 Ok for the same request. so does it mean from vugen script (web http protocol) we can not find such performance issue where browser failed to load web page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebHTTP you are only simulating the transport layer and you will not be able to find browser issues.
For browser issues you will have to do a functional test with a functional testing tool (e.g. UFT).

You can "cheat" though and use 1 TruClient virtual user in conjunction with the other WebHttp virtual users and then you will most likely be able to detect the problem.